# Show recipient as UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

Similar to `iPhone` mail, I want to display recipients as `UIButton`. But I am not able to implement it correctly.
I am creating all recipients over a single UILabel and then assigning attributed text to it.

```
NSMutableArray *arrRecipients = [NSMutableArray new];

if([message.Recipients containsString:@", "])
{
    NSArray *arr = [message.Recipients componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++)
    {
        [arrRecipients addObject:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
else
{
    [arrRecipients addObject:message.Recipients];
}

NSString *recipientString = @"";

for(int i = 0; i < arrRecipients.count; i++)
{
    if([recipientString isEqual:@""])
        recipientString = [arrRecipients objectAtIndex:i];
    else
        recipientString = [recipientString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", [arrRecipients objectAtIndex:i]]];

}

NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", NSLocalizedString(@"to", nil), recipientString]];

for(NSString *value in arrRecipients)
{
    NSRange range = [recipientString rangeOfString:value];
    [str addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:205.0/255.0 green:205.0/255.0 blue:205.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] range:NSMakeRange(range.location + 4, range.length)];
}

UILabel *recipients = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, subject.frame.origin.y + subject.frame.size.height + 6, viewHeader.frame.size.width - 5, 20)];
recipients.attributedText = str;
recipients.numberOfLines = 0;
recipients.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
[viewHeader addSubview:recipients];
[recipients sizeToFit];

[viewHeader sizeToFit];
```

Results :

[image]

Not a quite good one.

How can I improve it ?

Comment: As "UIButton", with what kind of customization/appearance? Else, you may want to use `NSLinkAttributeName`?

Comment: You can also achieve same using `UICollectionView` or you can use [TURecipientBar from github](https://github.com/davbeck/TURecipientBar).

Comment: Look at this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jstokenfield

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like in mail or in other apps we can have a functionality of tags which can differentiate between list of items.
Below links may help you out:
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=tags
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/aktagsinputview

Answer (score 5):

You should use `UITextView` with attributed string key `NSLinkAttributeName` and handle tap on each name with its respective `UITextView` delegate.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", NSLocalizedString(@"to", nil), recipientString]];

for(NSString *value in arrRecipients)
{
    NSRange range = [recipientString rangeOfString:value];
    [str addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:205.0/255.0 green:205.0/255.0 blue:205.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] range:NSMakeRange(range.location + 4, range.length)];
    [str addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value:"a custom url scheme" range:NSMakeRange(range.location + 4, range.length)];

}
```

Then handle in this method:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
{
   if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"myurl"]) {
       // Handle tap

       return NO;
   }

   return YES;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to set the textView's "editable" property to NO and "selectable" to YES in order for the name to be clickable.

Comment: The issue with this implementation is, when the link extends to two lines, there is no gap in between the linked text. Very much similar to what I have attached in my question.

Answer (score 3):

Like what @Mohamad Sheikh suggested, you could use a UITextView with attributed string or actually subclass it to create your own is easier to manage in my opinion.

If you don't mind using external library, in one of my project i uses this `pod` [CLTokenInputView](https://github.com/clusterinc/CLTokenInputView). Is really easy to use and save me hours of implementing my own. The swift version is [here](https://github.com/rlaferla/CLTokenInputView-Swift).

Then just follow the protocol in the `CLTokenInputViewDelegate` and implement your code in the following:

`func tokenInputView(aView:CLTokenInputView, didAddToken token:CLToken)`

`func tokenInputView(aView:CLTokenInputView, didRemoveToken token:CLToken)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this one. Have you seen https://github.com/venmo/VENTokenField ?